# Allocate EC2 through Ansible

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x

When creating an EC2 instance through Ansible, how do you specify the security group (this is for a Amazon VPC environment that is not the account default)?  In my case, I am attempting to assign a security group (that currently exists) to my webserver EC2 instance that restricts traffic to only the traffic coming from the ELB that sits in front of it.  If I try the following:

```
- name: Create webserver instance
  ec2: 
    key_name: "{{ project_name }}-{{ env }}-key"
    image: "{{ image }}"
    instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
    instance_tags: '{"Name":"{{ project_name }}-{{ env }}-{{ webserver_name }}","Owner":"{{ project_name }}", "Type":"{{ webserver_name }}","Environment":"{{ env }}"}'
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    group: "{{ security_group_name }}"
    wait: true
  register: ec2
```

where {{ security_group_name }} is the 'Group Name' found in the AWS console, I receive the following error: 'Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty'

If I try the following:

```
- name: Create webserver instance
  ec2: 
    key_name: "{{ project_name }}-{{ env }}-key"
    image: "{{ image }}"
    instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
    instance_tags: '{"Name":"{{ project_name }}-{{ env }}-{{ webserver_name }}","Owner":"{{ project_name }}", "Type":"{{ webserver_name }}","Environment":"{{ env }}"}'
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    group_id: "{{ security_group_id }}"
    wait: true
  register: ec2
```

where {{ security_group_id }} is the 'Group Id' found in the AWS console (such as sg-xxxxxx), I receive the same error.  The Ansible documentation stated that 'group' and 'group_id' are for the specification of the security group (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html).

The only thing I can think of is that AWS cannot find the security group because I am creating it and it does not know the VPC to place it in or it is placing it in my default VPC and cannot find the security group as it is in a different VPC.

So, maybe a better question is, how to I specify the VPC for a particular EC2 instance (when I have multiple VPCs in a region)?

Comment: Please make sure that `region` parameter and `AWS_REGION` or `EC2_REGION` environment variables are correct. If you create group with `ec2_group`, check that you use correct `vpc_id` parameter.

Comment: Not creating a group but an ec2 instance.

Comment: can you refer this github repo: https://github.com/arbabnazar/ansible-aws-roles for detail instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I receive the following error: 'Value () for parameter groupId is invalid. The value cannot be empty'

It sounds like those variables aren't defined; where are you defining them?  Does it work when you don't use a variable, but put in the value directly?

> So, maybe a better question is, how to I specify the VPC for a particular EC2 instance (when I have multiple VPCs in a region)?

The VPC is implied by other values, notably `group`/`group_id` and `vpc_subnet_id`.

One of the main advantages of using `group_id` instead of `group` is that you'll get an error if you accidentally use a subnet for the wrong VPC, whereas if you have security groups with the same names in multiple VPCs, using `group` and an incorrect `vpc_subnet_id` will successfully launch a machine in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify the `VPC ID` in your playbook. Instead you specify the `vpc_subnet_id`. AWS can figure out the VPC based on subnet id. You are not specifying the subnet id, so AWS assumes that you want to launch it in `EC2 Classic`. Since the specified security group is not found in `EC2 Classic`, you are getting the `not found` or `invalid` error.

How to fix this? Find the `id` of the subnet where you want to launch the instance. Each VPC can have one more public and/or private subnets. From AWS dashboard, select `VPC Service` which will list the subnets and VPCs. Find the subnet you want to launch in, and specify its id in the playbook.

```
vpc_subnet_id: subnet-29e63245
```